# JSON add value on click

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to make a site of restaurant and now doing some table reservation. So far have one problem:
I have a JSON of tables and want to add date (day/time) to it, when table was clicked.
The problem's next - when I click on some table, the date adds to all JSON elements. And I wand to add it only to the element I clicked.
Here is link to codepen:
https://codepen.io/wilchilly/pen/qBEvegW
(To see the result click on some table and open console)

My HTML:

```
<p class="href-to italic" id="showMore">Show tables</p>

<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
  <div class="tables-wrapper" id="tables-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
fetch('tables.json')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
    const myJson = json;
    let showTables = document.getElementById('showMore');

    //show elements on page
    function loadGoods(data) {
        let out = '';
        for (let key in data) {
            if (data[key].isAvailable == false) {
                out += '<div class="single-table not-available"  data-name="' + data[key]['name'] + '" data-art="' + data[key]['id'] + '">';
                out += '<h4>' + data[key]['name'] + '</h4>';
                out += '<p>' + data[key]['location'] + '</p>';
                out += '</div>';
            } else {
                out += '<div class="single-table"  data-name="' + data[key]['name'] + '" data-art="' + data[key]['id'] + '">';
                out += '<h4>' + data[key]['name'] + '</h4>';
                out += '<p>' + data[key]['location'] + '</p>';
                out += '</div>';
            }
        }

        $('#tables-wrapper').html(out);
    }

    //set Date (day/time)
    function setDate() {
        for (let key in myJson) {
            myJson[key]['date']['day'] = '10/02';
            myJson[key]['date']['time'] = '20:00';
        }
        console.log(myJson);
    }

    showTables.addEventListener('click', function () {
        loadGoods(myJson);

        let singleTable = document.getElementsByClassName('single-table');
        Array.from(singleTable).forEach(function (element) {
            element.addEventListener('click', setDate);
        });
    });

})
```

JSON:

```
    [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "index": 0,
        "name": "Table 1",
        "capacity": 5,
        "isAvailable": true,
        "location": "Bar",
        "date": {
            "day": " ",
            "time": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "index": 1,
        "name": "Table 2",
        "capacity": 5,
        "isAvailable": true,
        "location": "Patio",
        "date": {
            "day": " ",
            "time": " "
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "index": 2,
        "name": "Table 3",
        "capacity": 5,
        "isAvailable": true,
        "location": "Bar",
        "date": {
            "day": " ",
            "time": " "
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Table 4",
        "capacity": 6,
        "isAvailable": true,
        "location": "Inside",
        "date": {
            "day": " ",
            "time": " "
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: can you post a demo online?

Comment: Sure! Here:
https://codepen.io/wilchilly/pen/qBEvegW
(To see the result - click on some table, then in console will be array with date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. This might be helpful for someone with a similar question.

```js
function setDate() {
  let inputDay = document.getElementById('form-data').value;
  let inputTime = document.getElementById('form-time').value;

  for (let i = 0; i < myJson.length; i++) {
    if (this.getAttribute('data-art') == myJson[i].id) {
      myJson[i]['date']['day'] = inputDay;
      myJson[i]['date']['time'] = inputTime;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the index from the iteration on table creation as id (or any attr you like) for example (you will probably need a classic for or a foreach) and then, in the event you attached pass the click event as param. Finally you just use the event.target to get the id (or the attr you choose) of the element and use it in the setDate func.